# Python, Unittest + Pandas DataFrames: can this assertion test = a bool value (without getting a ValueError)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assert, python-unittest

I'm creating a class based only on inferences I gather by looking at pre-written Unittest test cases. Unittest will test my class and run assertion tests against its functions.

**I cannot change the assertion tests**: I didn't write them.

Me not being terribly advanced with Unittest or Pandas, I still question whether some of the pre-written assertion tests could ever return True... or even False. I'm here to single out just one for now. I would love to know if there is any way (like, any way that I'm not seeing right now) that this one test case could ever return either True or False.

The comparison that is being made is if the value of a column in a Pandas DataFrame == some value. Like, `assertTrue(df['Age'] == 21)`. The error—which I totally understand *why* I get—is `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Makes sense: I'm getting back a pandas Series, which returns a series of bools, not a single value. Plus, if you (could even) use the methods mentioned above, you won't get a number anyway, but a True or False value, such that `False == 21` or `True == 21`, both of which = False.

Yet, from the assertion test format, `assertTrue(df['Age'] == 21)`, it seems like the test is expecting a single value anyway.

And if that's possible, *I have no intuitive idea how that could be made to work.* So, my question is: can it work? Does it involve some kind of operator overloading, or what?

Again, I consider myself new to both Pandas and Unittest. I'll be glad to provide any other necessary information, including more code, but my question is more about whether the aforementioned assertion test can be dealt with or not, and if so, how one might approach it.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the assertion supposed to hold true for every row? Should it hold for at least 1? What is expected here? If you don't know, ask somebody who does.

Comment: I may well have to ask. Right now I can't see the assertion passing as it is.

Comment: Not unless `df` is a `pd.Series({'Age': 21})` or a dictionary `{'Age': 21}`.

Comment: Consider .any () or .all ()